# Unable to get Object Id from Get Url in Postman

Tags: go, get, postman, mgo, go-gin

It Seems like my url is mismatching as its showing a 404 error, I tried changing the url at both postman and my code too.Also tried to work out with object id conversion to see if the 404 is being caused by that.

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/get-custone/:_id", getDetailone)
    r.Run()
} 
func getDetailone(c *gin.Context) {
    session := connect()
    defer session.Close()
    col := session.DB("test").C("cust")
    var results Person
    idstring:=c.Param("_id")
    oid:=bson.ObjectId(idstring)
    err := col.Find(bson.M{"_id":oid}).One(&results)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": "success",
    })
}
```

here's the screenshot from Postman

[image]

Comment: Why is the query param "_id" ? Is this how the design is ? Not that its not supposed to be like that but just wondering

Also, can you make a call without the query parameter and let know if you are able to see a response ?

Comment: that id part , i didn't get you there..without query parameter and removing _id from this  r.GET("/get-custone/", getDetailone) at main function returns  gives me a success message

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the success response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postman you are trying to pass `_id` as a query string whereas you are waiting for a path parameter in your code.

What you want to do is that:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/get-custone/5b7d...
```

If you prefer using query string parameter, you should rather do something like that (I did not test the code):

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/get-custone", getDetailone)
    r.Run()
} 
func getDetailone(c *gin.Context) {
    session := connect()
    defer session.Close()
    col := session.DB("test").C("cust")
    var results Person
    idstring:= c.Query("_id")
    oid:=bson.ObjectId(idstring)
    err := col.Find(bson.M{"_id":oid}).One(&results)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": "success",
    })
}
```